# misalignment error in pixels

Tags: image, camera-calibration, image-stitching

I have two cameras I have calibrated the cameras considering there position at the same point. But actually the positions of the cameras is slightly different than considered during calibration. This caused a parallax error. Now when I capture a point with these two cameras I get a misalignment in the images due to parallax Now I want to calculate this misalignment in pixels.

I tried to calculate the misalignment in m

Z(measured) = Z(calib) + (Du /tan a1 + tan a2)
Z(measured) is actual distance from cam to object in m
Z(calib) is distance from camera to calibration marker point.
Du is distance between the projected point of the object captured by two cameras on image plane in meters
tan a1 = (distance between camera position during calibration and actual camera 1 position/ distance between camera position during calibration and position of calibration marker point)

tan a2 = (distance between camera position during calibration and actual camera 2 position/ distance between camera position during calibration and position of calibration marker point)

How can I now convert this value of Du in meters to pixels

Comment: Why not perform the calibration one more time and have the correct parameterization?

Answer (score 0):

If you know what the ground sample distance of your image you can use that to determine how much distance a pixel represents and use that number to convert meters to pixels.
Ground sample distance is calculated as:

```
GSD = D/F* PS
GSD = Ground sample distance
D = Distance to object (from camera)
F = Focal Length
PS = Pixel size (calculated using Photo dimension/Camera Sensor Dimension. 
PS should be almost if not exactly the same when comparing Width and Height result.
```

Having GSD you can then work backwards to determine number of pixels based on distance in meters (note this means you will want units to all be in meters).